# Converting Directx 9 shaders for Directx 11.1 (Windows Store Apps)

Tags: directx, windows-store-apps, hlsl, directx-11, directx-9

I am trying to learn writing DirectX shaders with hlsl for a DirectX Windows Store App.

Visual Studio 2012 has a great tool to help designing shaders but since I am novice in shaders, I can not interpret the exported hlsl source and possibly alter it to fine-tune the shaders.

What I would like to have actually is to be able to re-use some of shaders written for DirectX 9 (mostly to be used with XNA). Also, net has very useful tutorials to teach shaders for DirectX 9. I am comparing the shaders for DirectX 9 and 11 but can not see how I may convert existing DirectX 9 shaders to the ones I may use in DirectX 11.

I think I am missing some basic concepts to dive into details on this. Please let me know the differences between the shaders in the two platforms.

A reference to a document or a good tutorial will greatly be appreciated.

The biggest difference I see is that DirectX 11 shaders has a main function like below although old shaders do not.

```
P2F main(V2P pixel)
```

Instead they have something like below:

```
technique10 FireTechnique
{
    pass pass0
    {
        SetBlendState(AlphaBlendingOn, float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 0xFFFFFFFF);
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, FireVertexShader()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, FirePixelShader()));
        SetGeometryShader(NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476190(v=vs.85).aspx

But really maybe you should get a handle on the DX9 shaders first (FXComposer? I'm not sure how you have sourced these DX9 shaders) -- it feels a bit like you'd like to translate from one language you don't know into another you don't know without learning the first one.

Comment: I have to learn DX11 shaders but have only DX9 shader examples. If I had the time and energy, I would setup an environment to first learn and try DX9, then learn the differences between DX9 and DX11 and then start writing in DX11. I was hoping to short-circuit DX9 and directly moving to DX11 with some helps like giving references or possibly listing differences.

Comment: I know that's exactly what you seem to be asking -- to translate Chinese poetry into Russian when you speak neither. The core language is pretty much the same between DX9 HLSL and DX11 HLSL, but the parts for managing DirectX state are changed. If you don't know what "DirectX state" means, then you have a serious uphill climb to understand blending states, shader stages, etc.

Comment: I have already started to understand things. Thanks for the link.